# Interacting with an Android/iOS date picker or time picker using Selenium

Tags: android, ios, selenium, datepicker, timepicker

I am trying to write some Selenium tests for a web form that includes date and time input elements (i.e., `<input type="date">`). On mobile devices, clicking on the input field automatically brings up an OS-specific picker. However, I have no idea how to interact with one using Selenium.

I looked at these SO questions:

[Select a date from date picker using Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398575/select-a-date-from-date-picker-using-selenium-webdriver)

[Example of touch event with webdriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884878/example-of-touch-event-with-webdriver-python)

But they both assume you know the `id` of the element to tap. I've tried every method I could imagine to specify a field of the picker (listing all the elements on the page, inspecting the HTML source, using Chrome's remote debugger) but to no avail. How do I do it?

Comment: interesting question. Few questions since I am not into Selenium on mobile devices. Can you get access to the element by searching for "type=date"?

Comment: I can get access to the `<input>` element itself, but from what I can tell, that is distinct from the picker that pops up.

Comment: selenium should keep the focus on the current element/window. so what happen if you click in the input and after do: driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])

Comment: Other possible scenario. Use the self.driver.switch_to.active_element()

Comment: Unfortunately when the picker pops up, `drv.window_handles == ['NATIVE_APP']` (just one window). As for `switch_to_active_element`, that resulted in `WebDriverException: Message: The requested command is currently not yet supported by selendroid.`

Comment: Ah, wait a second. The first approach is actually working. Before the picker pops up, there are two window handles: `'WEBVIEW_0'` and `'NATIVE_APP'`. Switching to the `'NATIVE_APP'` window gets me access to the picker. I need to poke around a bit more, but thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: You are welcome. Please update here any new finding

Comment: So for the date picker I can't really figure out how to select a date, but clicking the "OK" button works fine. The time picker on the other hand... on Android at least I ran into this problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79948

Comment: instead of selecting can you simple submit values as 01012015 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70864/discussion-between-user1475412-and-aberna).